# How long does it take to boot from a LiveUSB?

Tags: dual-boot, live-usb, windows-10

I downloaded Ubuntu 18.04 and created a bootable USB drive on Windows 10. I selected the boot from USB option, and the monitor went black. The power button on the monitor has been blinking slowly for about an hour and the screen has been black the whole time. I have a Intel Core i7 processor. When do I know that there's a problem? If there is a problem, how do I restart the process/get out of the black screen?

Comment: When things work, you measure the boot time in seconds (not minutes) in a computer with a core i7 processor and with USB 3. But there may be several bottlenecks. What you describe is not slowness, but there is a problem. I suspect the graphics driver. Maybe the [boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808) `nomodeset` would help.

Comment: 1/2 a minute on an i7. " and the monitor went black." Start with a  boot with the "safe graphics" option.

Comment: if you are using nvidia graphics card for display output it will not work because nvidia drivers are not available from the bootable usb. those need to be downloaded after install is complete. It's a catch 22, i would suggest you check if you have any onboard graphics from intel and use that instead. Those drivers should work

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a very slow machine -- probably below the specs that will run Windows 10 -- it shouldn't take anything like that long to start, at least to the "try" or "install" choice.  That doesn't seem applicable to a Core i7.

With no error message on your screen, it's likely there's a graphics problem.  If the thumb drive weren't bootable, you'd have gotten an error; almost anything else that could go wrong would also give a (text) error message rather than a blank screen -- but some graphics problems will result in the OS thinking it's working, and Ubuntu Live is sitting there, waiting for you to respond to a prompt you can't see.

To get out of the black screen, you should be able to hit CTL-ALT-DEL several times to prompt a reboot, or if that fails, just use the power button (you're likely to have to hold it for up to five seconds).